# Need to rename many files on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, rename, multiple-instances

I have around 1000 files named "Home Movie - 01 - First Birthday" and "Home Movie 02 01 12"

I need to rename these to just "Home Movie". Is there any way to do this? Running Ubuntu 12.04

Thanks,
Kyle

Comment: Please tell us more about the logic of your renaming scheme, like removing all digits / hyphens, or there's other rules?  Are they scattered over 1000 folders or have 1000 different files with similar names under the same folder?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/283145/pattern-based-batch-file-rename-in-terminal ...... or http://askubuntu.com/questions/72628/how-to-batch-rename-files-with-variables

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Double Commander](http://sourceforge.net/p/doublecmd/wiki/Download/) which is a FOSS clone for Total Commander, 
this application have a tool (GUI) for mass file rename which enable you to preview your result before applying it, and it is very recommenced.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest mmv from the mmv package:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/mmv.1.html